# Hibernate make right database query but return null entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, vaadin

I'm working in a Vaadin java project with spring and hibernate. I have the next Entity in my project:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "listarAreas", query = "SELECT a FROM AreaFuncional a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "obtenerAreaPorId", query = "SELECT a FROM AreaFuncional a where a.id=?") })
public class AreaFuncional implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nombre;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "area_pertenencia_id")
    private AreaFuncional areaPertenencia;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AreaFuncional> subAreas;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Empleado> empleados;
    private String telefonos;
    private String email;

    public AreaFuncional() {
        this.subAreas = new HashSet<AreaFuncional>();
        this.empleados = new HashSet<Empleado>();
    }
....
```

Then I have the next query:

```
public AreaFuncional obtenerAreaPorId(Long id) {
     AreaFuncional area = (AreaFuncional)
     getSessionFactory().getNamedQuery("obtenerAreaPorId").setLong(0, id)
     .uniqueResult();
    if (area == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("No existe el area con id " + id);
    return area;

}
```

When I execute the query, I get the correct mysql query for database:

```
01:49:11,785 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-42 hibernate.SQL:109 - select areafuncio0_.id as id1_0_, areafuncio0_.area_pertenencia_id as area_per5_0_, areafuncio0_.email as email2_0_, areafuncio0_.nombre as nombre3_0_, areafuncio0_.telefonos as telefono4_0_ from AreaFuncional areafuncio0_ where areafuncio0_.id=?
```

If I execute the mysql statement in console, I get the correct answer, but Hibernate returns null object.

I can't get the error.
Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use named query then you should use it as:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "obtenerAreaPorId", query = "SELECT a FROM AreaFuncional a where a.id= :id") })
```

and

```
 getSessionFactory().getNamedQuery("obtenerAreaPorId").setLong("id", id)
```

Comment: I think the two posibilities are ok. I have many other named queries done in the same way

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not pass the id parameter;
Test this one :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "obtenerAreaPorId", query = "SELECT a FROM AreaFuncional a where a.id=:id") })

getSessionFactory().getNamedQuery("obtenerAreaPorId").setParameter("id",myId)
```